# LocalDB vs SQL Server in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, localdb

If I install SQL Server, does it overwrite the localDB? Is my database using the localDB still usable?

I'm using Visual Studio 2012..

My projects from the previous version.. VB.NET 2005 when I open it in VB.NET 2012 there are lots of errors now.. here's one of the problem

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

can help..tnx in advance...

Comment: What kind of application is this, desktop or web?

Comment: Check your `<connectionStrings>` aren't being inherited from another configuration file.

Comment: still got that error..tsk..

Comment: Post your connection string here. Usually Sql server does not overwrite localDB. I guess the problem come from localDB configuration.

Comment: my project seems fine now..but when i open my SQL SERVER CONFIGURATION MANAGER my SQL SERVER SERVICES says "the remote procedure call failed 0x80076be"..what's wrong ?